# Android ViewFlipper animation does not render background?

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I'm using a ViewFlipper with two ListViews. When setting a background drawable on the ViewFlipper, the animation performed when "flipping" only renders the foreground, and background is black! When animation is done, the background appears.
Is there a known problem with animating the background "layer" of a view?

Also, the animation performance/frame rate on my HTC Hero decreases significantly when adding the background.

Any ideas or solutions? Thanks!

/Morten

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I found the following workaround. You have to set the background on the view being animated, not on the flipper. So for consistency, this would mean you have to set the same background on all the top level views contained in your flipper.